# Add a new column with sum of count to a dataframe according to informations from another in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, merge, datatable

I would need help in order to add count column into a table called `tab1` according to another `tab2`.

Here is the first tab :

**tab1**

```
    Event_Groups Other_column
1      1_G1,2_G2            A
2           2_G1            B
3           4_G4            C
4 7_G5,8_G5,9_G5            D
```

as you can see  in `Event_Groups` column I have 2 information (`Event` and `Groups` numbers separated by a "_"). These informations will also be found in `tab2$Group` and `tab2$Event` and the idea is for each element within rows in `tab1` (separated by a comma) , to count the number of rows within `tab2` where `VALUE1 < 10` AND `VALUE2 > 30` and then add this count into **tab1** in a new column called `Sum_count`.

Here is the
**tab2**

```
  Group Event VALUE1 VALUE2
1    G1     1      5     50  <- VALUE1 < 10 & VALUE2 > 30 : count 1  
2    G1     2     6      20  <- VALUE2 < 30  : count 0 
3    G2     2     50     50  <- VALUE1 > 10  : count 0
4    G3     3      0      0
5    G4     1      0      0
6    G4     4      2     40  <- VALUE1 < 10 & VALUE2 > 30 : count 1 
7    G5     7      1     70  <- VALUE1 < 10 & VALUE2 > 30 : count 1 
8    G5     8      4     67  <- VALUE1 < 10 & VALUE2 > 30 : count 1 
9    G5     9      3     60  <- VALUE1 < 10 & VALUE2 > 30 : count 1
```

**Example :**

- For instance for the first element of row1 in **tab1**: `1_G1`
  we see in **tab2** (row1) that **VALUE1 < 10** & **VALUE2 > 30**, so I count 1.
- For the seconde element (row1) : `2_G2` we see in **tab2** (row3) that **VALUE1 > 10**, so I count 0.

And here is the expected result **tab1** dataframe;

```
Event_Groups     Other_column Sum_count
1_G1,2_G2        A            1
2_G1             B            0
4_G4             C            1
7_G5,8_G5,9_G5   D            3
```

I dot not know if I am clear enough, do not hesitate to ask questions.

---

Here are the two tables in dput format if it can helps:

**tab1**

```
structure(list(Event_Groups = structure(1:4, .Label = c("1_G1,2_G2", 
"2_G1", "4_G4", "7_G5,8_G5,9_G5"), class = "factor"), Other_column =
structure(1:4, .Label = c("A",  "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor")),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

**tab2**

```
structure(list(Group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L), .Label = c("G1", "G2", "G3", "G4", "G5"), class = "factor"), 
    Event = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 9L), VALUE1 = c(5L, 
    6L, 50L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L), VALUE2 = c(50, 20, 50, 
    0, 0, 40, 70, 67, 60)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

tab1 %>% 
  mutate(Event_Groups = as.character(Event_Groups)) %>% 
  separate_rows(Event_Groups, sep = ",") %>% 
  left_join(., 
            tab2 %>% 
              unite(col = "Event_Groups", Event, Group) %>% 
              mutate(count = if_else(VALUE1 < 10 & VALUE2 > 30,1L, 0L))) %>%
  group_by(Other_column) %>% 
  summarise(Event_Groups = paste(unique(Event_Groups), collapse = ","),
            Sum_count = sum(count)) %>% 
  select(Event_Groups, everything())

#> Joining, by = "Event_Groups"
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   Event_Groups   Other_column Sum_count
#>   <chr>          <fct>            <int>
#> 1 1_G1,2_G2      A                    1
#> 2 2_G1           B                    0
#> 3 4_G4           C                    1
#> 4 7_G5,8_G5,9_G5 D                    3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks you very much for that ! what if I have mutliple Other_column that I need to keep in the ouptut but that are not specially involved in the process?

Comment: Can you try to add them all to the `group_by` where we have only `Other_column` right now? If you have many other variables you can use `across` inside `group_by`.

Comment: Yes sure, juste another question: Why did you put ```1L, 0L``` into the mutate line ?

Comment: `0L` and `1L` are part of the `ifelse` but you could use `as.numeric` instead of the `ifelse` statement, then you wouldn’t need `0L` and `1L`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)

tab1 %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  separate_rows(Event_Groups, sep = ",") %>% 
  separate(Event_Groups, into =  c("Event", "Group"), sep="_", convert = T) %>% 
  left_join(tab2 %>% 
             mutate(count = as.numeric(VALUE1 < 10 & VALUE2 > 30)), 
            by = c("Event", "Group")) %>% 
  unite(Event_Groups, Event, Group) %>% 
  group_by(rowname)  %>% 
  summarise(Event_Groups = toString(Event_Groups),
            Other_column = unique(Other_column),
            count =sum(count))
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  rowname Event_Groups     Other_column count
  <chr>   <chr>            <chr>        <dbl>
1 1       1_G1, 2_G2       A                1
2 2       2_G1             B                0
3 3       4_G4             C                1
4 4       7_G5, 8_G5, 9_G5 D                3
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, what if I have mutliple Other_column that I need to keep in the ouptut but that are not specially involved in the process?